# ValueError: malformed string?

Tags: python, django

le "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/project_name/../project_name/apps/accounts/decorators.py", line 44, in inner_decorator
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/project_name/../project_name/apps/reports/views.py", line 97, in hiv_report_new
    return form.get_itable(pk)

File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/project_name/../project_name/apps/reports/forms.py", line 433, in get_itable
    custom_data =  ast.literal_eval(report_qs[0]['query'])

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 68, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 62, in 
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 62, in 
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 67, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')

ValueError: malformed string

Comment: What's your question? Why did "hive" change to "project_name"? Looks like there is a bug in hive/project_name

Comment: Have you checked the files of your project that is mentioned in the log?

Comment: how to get rid of  "ValueError: malformed string "

Comment: input storing in db :
{'PatientProfile__medical_home_last_visit': {'start': datetime.date(2013, 11, 21), 'end': datetime.date(2013, 11, 30)}, 'PatientProfile__creation_date': {'start': datetime.date(2013, 11, 23), 'end': datetime.date(2013, 11, 30)}, 'PatientProfile__creation_dt': [datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 30, 0, 0)], 'PatientProfile__update_dt': [datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 21, 0, 0)], 'data_model_name': ['PatientProfile']}

Comment: when i try to fetch via model_name.obj.objects.all()

i am getting this error if i remove date then its working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation to `ast.literal_eval`:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
>   Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
>   and None.

The whole point of that function is that you can only use built-in datatypes. `datetime.date` is not one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use literal_eval with a string containing the "datetime.date"? That would cause that error

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("datetime.date(2013, 11, 23)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: yes i am using literal_eval but how to solve it?

Comment: you'll need to change the way you serialise/deserialise your data

Comment: how to change serialize way ?

Comment: def done(self, request, form_list):
    model_form, field_form = form_list
    query = SortedDict()
    for field_name in field_form.fields:
        app, model, field = field_name.split('__')
        name = '%s__%s' % (model, field)
        value = field_form.cleaned_data[field_name]
        #print value
        if value or value == 0:
            query[name] = value
            print value

    query['data_model_name'] = [model.split('__')[1] for model in field_form.model_list]
    Model_name.objects.create(name=model_form.cleaned_data['report_name'],query=query)